# bitand matlab wrong result

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation

I have a 64bits number which must be split in 4 numbers of 16bits each.
I'm currently using this form:

```
temp(ii) = fread(fd,1,'*uint64');
A(ii,1) = bitand(bitshift(temp(ii),-48),hex2dec('FFFF'));
A(ii,2) = bitand(bitshift(temp(ii),-32),hex2dec('FFFF'));
A(ii,3) = bitand(bitshift(temp(ii),-16),hex2dec('FFFF'));
A(ii,4) = bitand(temp(ii),hex2dec('FFFF'));
```

Everyone is correct but the last one. If you take this number 63614152207040708 the last 16bits give 196. Matlab gives me 192. If I cast the value with uint16() or with cast(63614152207040708, 'uint16') the result is 65535.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab does not *overflow* operations on integral types, it just saturates the value at the minimum or maximum level. So `uint16(63614152207040708)` will always return the max `uint16` value (=65535).

Regarding the byte separation, look at the [`typecast`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) documentation. It can help you avoid painful manual bit manipulations:

```
a = uint64(63614152207040708) ;

typecast( a ,'uint16')
ans =
    196    253    188    226
```

Just watch the endianess or use `fliplr` if you want to reverse it:

```
>> fliplr( typecast( a ,'uint16') )
ans =
    226    188    253    196
```

---

note: also be careful that by default Matlab cast every number not explicitly typed into `double` (64 bit float) so `cast(63614152207040708, 'uint16')` is different than `cast(uint64(63614152207040708), 'uint16')`. The result is not different here because you are over the max but it can make a difference with other values. For example with your code:

```
a = 63614152207040708 ; %// this is cast by default as double
A(1) = bitand(bitshift(a,-48),hex2dec('FFFF'));
A(2) = bitand(bitshift(a,-32),hex2dec('FFFF'));
A(3) = bitand(bitshift(a,-16),hex2dec('FFFF'));
A(4) = bitand(a,hex2dec('FFFF'));
A =
   226   188   253   192
```

is different than :

```
a = uint64(63614152207040708) ; %// make sure we give Matlab a uint64
A(1) = bitand(bitshift(a,-48),hex2dec('FFFF'));
A(2) = bitand(bitshift(a,-32),hex2dec('FFFF'));
A(3) = bitand(bitshift(a,-16),hex2dec('FFFF'));
A(4) = bitand(a,hex2dec('FFFF'));
A
A =
   226   188   253   196
```

I see you are using the right `fread` precision specifier to read `uint64`, but make sure your `temp` array is also defined as `uint64` or the value you read is converted to `double` as soon as it's assigned to `temp(ii)`.